# windows piping to a c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, piping

I have the following c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//will find the last dot and return it's location
char * suffix_location(char *);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "not enough arguments!" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
            cout << argv[i] <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    //ignore first parameter (program name).
    argv ++;
    argc --;

    //the new suffix
    char * new_suffix = argv[0];

    argv++;
    argc--;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        char * a = suffix_location(argv[i]);
        if (a != NULL)
        {
            a[0] = NULL;
            cout << argv[i] << '.' << new_suffix << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char * suffix_location(char * file_name)
{
    char * ret = NULL;
    for (; * file_name; file_name++)
        if (*file_name == '.')
            ret = file_name;
    return ret;
}
```

I compiled it using the following command:

```
cl /EHsc switch_suffix.cpp
```

when I run

```
switch_suffix py a.exe b.txt
```

I get:

```
a.py
b.py
```

as expected. 
the promblem start when I try to pipe. running the following:

```
dir /B | swich_suffix py
```

results nothing, and running

```
 dir /B | swich_suffix py
```

results:

```
not enough arguments!
switch_suffix
```

The piping on the system works fine - I tried it on a few other programs. 
I tried creating a vs project and compiling the code from there - helped nothing.

whats wrong, and hoe can I fix it?

I'm running on win7, using vs2010 tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pipe to another program it goes to the standard input and not to the arguments in main.

This piece of code prints out what it receives on `stdin` to `stdout`, try this:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
      std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried with `cin.getline` to retrive the data into a `char *`. It didn't work. is there an actuall difference between the two?

Comment: Yes, std::string is an object for storing strings in C++.  The memory is managed for you and there are lots of nice methods built into it.  `char*` is a pointer to some chars that you have to manage yourself.  I would strongly urge you to use std::string when writing in C++.  If you're determined to use `char*` then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c

Answer (score 3):

when you pipe, the information that gets passed to your program is on stdin, not argv